# .NET Core runtime and SDK versions - target a specific runtime version?

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

We recently received the below error at a customer site which had the .NET Core 2.1.23 runtime installed. It was easily resolved by installing .NET Core 2.1.25 runtime.

```
> dotnet .\OurApp.Web.dll    
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App, version '2.1.25' was not found.
 - The following versions are installed:
    2.1.23 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

[image: Error message specifying inability to find compatible framework version]

Since the error outlined above, we have upgraded to .NET Core 3.1.

We'd quite like to specify a minimum version of the .NET Core runtime which we require our customers to install. Then we'd build future releases to work with that runtime version.
We'd like to not have to worry about the exact versions of VS/.NET/etc installed on different developer machines (and even build machines).

We know we can fix the .NET Core SDK version in our global.json. However with rollForward=disable that seems overly restrictive (e.g. fixing at 3.1.409 was good until updates removed the 3.1.409 SDK and installed 3.1.410). It seems we need rollForward=disable as [the example table in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/) has a row where only the minor version of the SDK changes (2.2.101 -> 2.2.102), but the runtime changes too (2.2.0 -> 2.2.1).

Am I misunderstanding something? How should we go about ensuring we can build DLLs that will run against a specific runtime version?

Would setting RuntimeFrameworkVersion help? Would it have preented the error we had at our customer site?

Comment: you set the target in your proj file. Based on this, your code development happens. Then, when you publish this is the Runtime it is published for. You can try specifying multiple target runtimes. In this case when you publish, you should get multiple folders, each for a different runtime. But whatever target runtime you have, deployment machine should have that runtime.

Comment: @T.S. We set <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> but in the example above we appear to have needed something more specific (2.1.23 when 2.1.25 was needed).